# How do I generate sequence logo of ATGC against each position in R?

Tags: r, sequence

I am new in R sorry for the naive question. I want to generate the seqlogo for each position using R. Can anyone guide me? Thank you so much in advance.

```
1  GATGGGGTGGGCAACTTAGAACTT
2  ATAACTGT
3  CAGAGGCGAACT
4  GGGCTAGGG
5  GGGGGGTGGCAGCACTAGC
6  GGGTAATATG
7  GTCGAGCGGT
```

Best

Answer (score 3):

It's good practice to google before asking on online forums. Searching for "r seqlogo" pointed me to the seqLogo BioConductor package, which might be really helpful to you: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/seqLogo/inst/doc/seqLogo.html

You will need your sequences aligned though.